# Can we walk to Blue car rental from KEF airport?

Tags: car-rentals, walking, kef

I am planning to land in KEF (iceland) early in the morning and depart before 8 AM. So I was wondering whether I can walk to the Blue car rental pickup and drop off locations from the airport or do I have to take a taxi?

I would appreciate it if someone who has tried or knows about can help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Their website](https://www.bluecarrental.is/useful-information/deliveries/office-pick-up/) is very clear.

> Once you clear customs and enter the arrivals hall, the car rental
> shuttle parking space is right outside – next to “Flybus Parking”.
> This shuttle will take you to the Rental Car Area where Blue Car
> Rental will be your second stop on its route. Quite convenient and
> easy to find.
>
> The shuttle runs from 06:00 – 18:00 every day with approximately 15
> minutes intervals. If you are picking up after 18:00 we ask you to
> walk over to our delivery office. Simply exit the airport on the
> departure side and there you can see our delivery office across the
> parking lot.
>
> Our delivery office at the Keflavik International Airport is located
> within 4 minutes walking distance from the airport at Blikavellir 3.
> Renters are also more than welcome to take the walk over to us during
> the day.

I've been there last Christmas and I confirm what they say. If it's a nice day, it's a very short walk (400m?) otherwise there's a shuttle bus connecting Airport and parkings (where the car rental is). There're also other private vans taking people to other car rentals further away, don't jump on one of those!

Comment: Do you know whether they allow early pickups and drop-offs? Like 4 AM in the morning?

Comment: Dunno, I went with another rental company. You'd need the office open for pickup, so I'd text the agency to ask their opening time, as they may depend also from the season (I was there at Christmas Day last year and 2/3 of the rental companies were closed). For drop-off, based on my experience, you can do it 24/7 as you may just park the car in their spots and drop the key in their letterbox. In my case case, they checked the car immediately at the drop-off, which was a good thing but I had to pay for a damaged door. PAY ATTENTION TO WIND GUSTS IN ICELAND!!